# copied the code as is from the book, but it wont show the output

Tags: python

```
# european call option inner value plot
# 02_MBV/inner_value_plot.py
```

## derivatives analytics with python

```
     import numpy as geek
     import matplotlib as mpl
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     mpl.rcParams ['font.family'] = 'serif'
```

## option strike

```
    K= 8000
```

## graphical output

```
     S = geek.linspace (7000,9000,100) # index level values
     h = geek.maximum ( S-K,0) # inner value of call option
     plt.figure ()
     plt.plot(S,h, lw =2.5) #inner value at maturity 
     plt.xlabel ('index level $_$ at maturity')
     plt.ylabel ('inner value of european call option')
     plt.grid (True) 
# plot does not show due to some unknown error
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To ensure that you get asweres (and not just downvotes) please make sure to properly explain What you are trying to do, how its supposed to work and what you think is the problem. tl;dr Write more text, not just dump code. Good luck on your further endeavors

Answer (score 0):

You need `plt.show` at the end of the script.

Comment: i added plt.show it shows an empty graph image.